# $A\iff B$ in terms of $\lnot$ and $\implies$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How to write the equivalence $A\iff B$ in terms of $\lnot$ and $\implies$?

I know that $A\implies B\equiv \lnot A\lor B$.

Can I say $A\iff B\equiv (\lnot A\lor B)\land (A\lor \lnot B)$? Is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that $A \leftrightarrow B $ is equivalent to $(\neg A \lor B) \land (\neg B \lor A)$, but that is not expressing the $\leftrightarrow$ in terms of (just) 
$\neg$ and $\rightarrow$.

HINT. How can you express $A \land B$ in terms of $\neg$ and $\rightarrow$?

Second hint: $A \leftrightarrow B$ is also equivalent to $(A\land B) \lor (\neg A \land \neg B)$

Comment: Adding to this: OP - you've already shown that $A\rightarrow B \equiv \neg A \lor B$. Do you know any formulae connecting $A\lor B$ with $A\land B$?

Comment: Yes, $A\land B \equiv \lnot (\lnot A\lor \lnot B)$

Comment: @MichelleGarcía Cool!  So now take my suggested equivalence for the $\leftrightarrow$, replace the $\land$'s with $\neg$'s and $\lor$'s, and then replace all $\lor$'s with $\neg$'s and $\rightarrow$'s.