# How to express the binary operators in terms of (only) $\implies$ and $\lnot$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
A & \text{B} &  \oplus &  \lnot \operatorname{Id}_2  & \lnot \operatorname{Id}_1 \\
\hline
V & V & F & F & F\\
V & F & V & V & F\\
F & V & V & F & V\\
F & F & F & V & V
\end{array}
$$

I don't know how to proceed with this exercise, how can I express the **exclusive or**?

I do not know how to relate it to the other equivalences, for instance with the normal **or** it's just $A\lor B\equiv \lnot A\implies B$, how will it be for the exclusive or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have at first be reassured that a solution exists by the interesting information found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).

Here is a way to express $a$ xor $b$ (xor = exclusive or) using $\lnot$ and $\implies$:

$$\tag{1}(b \implies a) \implies \lnot(a \implies b)$$

Honestly, I found it by (computer assisted) trial and error by privilegizing expressions with a certain symmetry.

Is there is a shorter one in terms of number of connectors ? Maybe. This one has the advantage of being very "symmetrical".

---

**Edit 1:** Proof of formula (1)

Using the fact that $P\rightarrow Q ≡ (\lnot P\lor Q)$, (1) is equivalent to

$$\lnot(\lnot b \lor a) \lor \lnot(\lnot a \lor b),$$

itself equivalent to:

$$(b \land \lnot a) \lor(a  \land \lnot b)$$

which is (one of) the definition(s) of "xor" operator.

---

**Edit 2 :** I had a look to your previous question ([$A\iff B$ in terms of $\lnot$ and $\implies$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2461054)) : you could have used the fact that "xor" is the same as the negation of $\Leftrightarrow$ in order to obtain at once a formula for "xor" operator.

Comment: trial and error really? Is that difficult?

Comment: @Jason Thanks. Corrected. The frontal $\lnot$  hadn't to be there.

Comment: Yes, but by CATI (Computer Assisted Trial and Error :). I have added a proof that you can use backwards as well for reaching the result in a straightforward way... Now I see how I should have proceeded...

Answer (score 1):

You can write either $(A\lor B)\land\lnot(A\land B)$ or $(\lnot A\Rightarrow B)\land(A\Rightarrow \lnot B)$. The first comes from the usual interpretation of exclusive or as meaning "$A$ or $B$ but not both $A$ and $B$", and the second one comes from noting that exclusive or is equivalent to $\lnot A\Leftrightarrow B$. Now we just use $P\lor Q\equiv\lnot P\Rightarrow Q$ and $P\land Q\equiv\lnot(P\Rightarrow\lnot Q)$ on either to obtain the expression

$$\lnot[(\lnot A\Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow\lnot(A\Rightarrow\lnot B)].$$