# Expressing identities in terms of $\lnot$ and $\land$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to express the binary operands ($\lnot Id_2,\lnot Id_1$) in terms of $\lnot$ and $\land$.

Can someone tell me if is correct this
$$\lnot Id_2\iff\lnot (A \land B) \land (A\land B) \land\lnot(A \land B)\land (A\land B)\iff \lnot (A \land B) \land (A\land B)$$?

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
A & \text{B} &  \oplus &  \lnot \operatorname{Id}_2  & \lnot \operatorname{Id}_1 \\
\hline
V & V & F & F & F\\
V & F & V & V & F\\
F & V & V & F & V\\
F & F & F & V & V
\end{array}
$$

Comment: No, that's not correct. If you were to evaluate that back on a truth-table you'll see it's not equivalent. Now, do you *have* to use $\land$?  Otherwise, why not just use $\neg B$ and $\neg A$ respectively?

Comment: @Bram28.. This is the correct answer....

Comment: @Bram28 ah right, so for $\lnot Id_2$ is $\lnot B$ and  $\lnot Id_1$ is  $\lnot A$ very easy and I didn't notice..

Comment: @hyprfrcb ... what is ...?

Comment: Your two last recent posts (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2461133) and (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2461054)  are about the same kind of exercise. It is not in the spirit of MSE to answer to routine exercices of the same type again and again.